# Unexpected directories and files while using collectstatic in django

Tags: python, django

[This is my django project](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AzmUp.png), there is two apps; polls and study

This is the setting of my static file settings.

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'
STATICFILES_DIRS = (
os.path.join(BASE_DIR,"study","static","HScard"),
)
STATIC_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "staticfiles")
```

I expected the 'python manage.py collectstatic' in the shell would copy static files to "staticfiles" from only in "study/static/HSCard"(due to STATICFILES_DIRS above).

However, "collectstatic" copied unexpected files below.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/H2Yfh.png)

Why are the files in admin and polls copied to staticfiles?? besides the files in admin folder were from here (a single example):

```
Copying 'C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\admin\static\admin\js\vendor\xregexp\xregexp.min.js'
```

Why does 'collectstatic' working like this and how can I fix it as I expected?

The version of django using is 2.0.7.
Thank you.

Comment: These are the static files for Django Admin.

Comment: @Josewails How can I avoid copying these files while excuting collectstatic?

Comment: You mean you don't want to include `admin` dir??

Comment: You can use `python manage.py collectstatic --noinput -i admin`

Comment: @seuling Yes, but if it is necessary, It doesn't really matter to include them. More than that, I just want to know why `STATICFILES_DIRS` doesn't working as I know. I knew `collectstatic` copying the files from where is in `STATICFILES_DIRS`. Isn't it right?

Comment: No, collectstatic copies from all the installed apps as well. That's the whole point.

Comment: @JinhoPark You're right. But it also include all third party apps' static for default - so you can serve all static files in one directory in production level. So if you don't want to include it, just remove after `coolectstatic`. Or if you really want to ignore it, you can use `--ignore` command but I will not recommend it. (check here https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/contrib/staticfiles/)

Comment: I almost got it, thank you all!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is due to the default [Staticfiles Finders](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/ref/settings/#staticfiles-finders) settings:

```
STATICFILES_FINDERS = [
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.FileSystemFinder',
    'django.contrib.staticfiles.finders.AppDirectoriesFinder',
]
```

The `AppDirectoriesFinder` will look through your apps listed in your `INSTALLED_APPS` setting. If there are files such as `admin/static/`, which are included in the admin by default, then they will also be found by `collect_static`. Your choices are to either:

1. Remove apps from INSTALLED_APPS (obviously they won't work any more, but they won't contribute static files either)
2. Add the STATICFILES_FINDERS setting as above, but without the  `AppDirectoriesFinder` setting. Then Django will only collect staticfiles that you have explicitly mentioned in STATICFILES_DIRS